# hibernate Field 'user_id' doesn't have a default value

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I working on hibernate project that have the following three entity,when I add onetomany relationship between the entities get Field 'user_id' doesn't have a default value .

when try to insert new topics I get

Hibernate: insert into topics (content, date, image, image_name) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
May 08, 2016 11:46:56 PM org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter logExceptions
WARNING: SQL Error: 1364, SQLState: HY000
May 08, 2016 11:46:56 PM org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter logExceptions
SEVERE: Field 'user_id' doesn't have a default value

and get same error when try to insert new like record

user class

```
public class User implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "user_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
private long id;

@Column(name = "first_name",  nullable = false, length = 10)
private String firstName;

@Column(name = "last_name",  nullable = false, length = 10)
private String lastName;

@Column(name = "role",  nullable = false, length = 10)
private String role;


@Column(name = "email", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 10)
private String email;


@Column(name = "password", nullable = false, length = 10)
private String password;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user")
private Set<Topics> topics=new HashSet<Topics>();

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user1")
private Set<Like> likes=new HashSet<Like>();

//getter and setter
```

like class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "likes")
 public class Like implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "likes_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
private long id;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false,insertable = false, updatable = false)
private User user1;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "topics_id", nullable = false,insertable = false,   updatable = false)
private Topics topics;
 //getter and setter
```

topics class

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "topics")
 public class Topics implements Serializable{

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "topics_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
private long id;

@Column(name = "content", unique = true, nullable = false)
private String content;

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name = "date")
private Date date;

@Column(name = "image_name")
private String imageName;

@Lob
@Column(name="image", columnDefinition="longblob")
private byte[] image;


@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false,insertable = false, updatable = false)
private User user;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "topics")
private Set<Like> likes=new HashSet<Like>();
 //getter and setter
```

hibernate configuration file

```
 <hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer">false</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/social</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
    <mapping class="com.pro.model.User"></mapping>
    <mapping class="com.pro.model.Topics"></mapping>
    <mapping class="com.pro.model.Like"></mapping>
</session-factory>
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably, You didn't set the User of Topics that you attempted to insert topics table.

One more thing, use singular class names. 
Topics -> Topic

Answer (score 0):

I see numerous problems here:

- Are you sure that **topics** are not ManyToMany  rather than OneToMany at all side (seems like not valid stuff)... (one people can interested in many topics, topics can contain many people)
- If you want to persist new topic with new user and like you should use @OneToMany(**cascade** = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE }) should work if you setup correctly in the fields, if you not, you may will be suffer from circular references...
- and I would rather use **GenerationType.SEQUENCE**, because AUTO is like a blackbox. You will not know exactly what is happening... (e.g. oracle will create a sequence to provide unique primary key)